# How to play an Youtube/Spotify playlist shuffling on a website

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, spotify

I am looking to play a Youtube or Spotify playlist shuffling on my website. So when they join my website, they will listen to a song off the playlist. I am guessing youtube would be very easy but I do not know how.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YOUTUBE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) and [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/). You will work with Javascript objects and JSON in return. Starting that you can show off a playlist or a youtube search result. Depending what you wanna do.

Read these documentations and if you wanna see some example about it, I am letting an own code with Youtube API: https://github.com/aipi/reampYoutubeAPI

It is good because you have an analytics and can see how often people interact with your API.

A example request code:

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
     part: "snippet",
     type: "video",
     q: encodeURIComponent($("#input-search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
     maxResults: 6,
     order: "viewCount",
     publishedAfter: "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
});
```